# Assign variables to all lines in a text file written in perl and use them to display in a HTML table

Tags: html, linux, perl, cgi

For example, I have a cgi where I have appended the shell script to a text file lstatus.txt as follows:

```
use IO::All;
use CGI;

system `bash /opt/apache/cgi-bin/lisa/lisapage3.sh > lstatus.txt`

io('lstatus.txt') > $data
Print << EOF;
<HTML>
<BODY>
<P>$data</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The output is as follows: EnterpriseDasboardService is Running. RegistryService is Running.PortalService is Running.VirtualServiceEnvironment is Running.

Now, I tried editing the text file lstatus.txt and the content in it is as follows:

```
EnterpriseDasboardService is Running > $abs
RegistryService is Running > $pqr
PortalService is Running > $qwe
VirtualServiceEnvironment is Running > $dfg
```

I have assigned the variables to each line in a text file as mentioned above. 
I need each variable to be used in the table tag  as follows:

```
<table>
  <th>STATUS</th>
      <tr>
         <td>$abs</td>
          .....
         <td>$dfg</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

I want the output to be displayed in a table which I could not do by using the above changes.

Comment: Yes, ./EnterpriseDashboardService status is a command and i want the output of it to be assigned to a variable and use that variable in the table.

Comment: Before proceeding further, can show me what you have tried? I mean show me your code.

Comment: Your new version of the question doesn't make much more sense. Why are you editing a text file? Having things like `> $abc` in a text file doesn't do anything and it just looks like a completely strange approach. Why are you doing that? Why not just read the text file and print out a html table without any variable names in the file?

Comment: I would suggest, write a parser inside your script which would process content in ```$data``` rather than editing it again.

Comment: Instead of doing all that weird stuff with `system` and redirecting a shell script's output to a file and then reading it... why not just have perl run it directly? `my $data = qx(/opt/apache/cgi-bin/lisa/lisapage3.sh);` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like following code bellow

Note: read documentation for [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use CGI;

my $filename = 'lstatus.txt';
my @arguments = ('/opt/apache/cgi-bin/lisa/lisapage3.sh','>',$filename);

system 'bash', @arguments;

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my @data = <$fh>;

close $fh;

chomp @data;

my $table = data2table(\@data);

$html =
"<html>
    <head>
        <title>Status webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        $table
    </body>
</html>
";

say $html;

sub data2table {
    my $data = shift;

    my $table;
    my $space = "\n\t\t";

    $table  = $space . '<table>';
    $table .= $space . "\t<tr><th>STATUS</th></tr>";
    $table .= $space . "\t<tr><td>$_</td></tr>" for @{$data};
    $table .= $space . '</table>';

    return $table;
}
```